# How to make every field able to process a request with several options in Django REST?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Suppose I own a store, and there is a database table with information about everything I sell; it basically records what I sold and to whom I sold it. I use Django REST to interface with said database, and I can access the table data via **/rest/purchases**.

I would like to filter those purchases by client, but I'd also like to be able to pass in an array of clients' IDs and get all the purchases they made. Here's the catch: I'm well aware that this can be easily achieved, either by creating a custom filter class inside the viewset class for this specific endpoint or by overriding the get_queryset method. The thing is that I want this functionality to be available for ALL fields in ALL my viewsets, and if I create another project later, I'd also want this functionality in all its viewsets and fields. So, changing the get_queryset method or adding custom filter_classes is not a viable option, because it takes up too much time.

**Bottom line:** is there a way to create this custom filter and inject it in all field of my project? Studying the DRF, I got to where the filters for each field are defined, but this happens in classes way too deep inside the DRF architecture (the *BaseFilterSet* class), so, I can't just change stuff there. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add default filter backends per the documentation here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

If the django filter backend doesn't suit your needs there are a few more pre baked ones that you can pick from. Or if you need to you can roll your own.